# Why is this SimpleDateFormat object's parse method not throwing a ParseException?

Tags: java

and yes, I've switched off the lenient option:

```
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    df.setLenient(false);

    String candidateDate = "1-1-1";

    try {
        System.out.println(df.parse(candidateDate));
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

I'm seeing in my console:

```
Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 CAT 1
```

Comment: Whys should it? Its a valid date.

Comment: It certainly is, but it does not enforce a non lenient parsing. I'd expect something like '0001-01-01'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of format characters is not an explicit indicator of the number of digits to be parsed.

Specific example from the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) concerning the **year** field:

> For parsing, if the number of pattern letters is more than 2, the year is interpreted literally, regardless of the number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

Because that is a valid date in your format. January 1, 1 (which was apparently a Saturday roughly 2013 years ago). If you want to test that the year has a certain number of digits you could do that before (or after) parsing.

Answer (score 0):

`"1-1-1"` is still an acceptable format of `"yyyy-MM-dd"`.

Try with illegal values like "1-75-40". then you will get an exception.